# How to select an associated product of a configurable product to display in catalogsearch page?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, configurable-swatches, configurable-product-options

Without any configuration, the green pant is shown by default when I search for 'yoga pant'. My question is How can I make, for example, blue pant size 34 and its price and stock status as well to display instead? I'm in Magento 2.3 btw. 
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Change all child product "Visibility => Catalog Search", after that run indexing and clean cache. Now check products in your storefront.

Comment: Come on. No, it has nothing to do with my issue. My question was how to display Blue or Red child in their parent preview instead of Green by default?

Comment: I believe they all lie in the file swatch-renderer.js but don't know how to edit.